# Contravariance in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, contravariance

I never truly understood generics in Java, so it seems to be the case with Kotlin. Consider the following code snippet (it's a contrived example):

```
class AnyComparator: Comparator<Any> {
    override fun compare(o1: Any, o2: Any): Int {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
}


fun <T> test() {
    val x: Comparator<in Double> = AnyComparator() // OK!
    val y: Comparator<in T> = AnyComparator() // Compilation error
}
```

The second assignment fails with the error

```
Type mismatch. 
Required: kotlin.Comparator<in T>
Found: AnyComparator
```

Now, if I understand correctly the `in` modifier indicates the `T` is only consumed by the generic type `Comparator` (it makes contravariant), so I should be able to assign any `Comparator` with type argument `E` which is the base class of `T`. Based on this, I should be able to assign `AnyComparator` to both variables `x` and `y`, since the type `Any` is the base class of every class in Kotlin. It turns out I can't, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It can be seem strange but `Any` is not the superclass of all kotlin classes but only of not nullable classes. The real superclass of all Kotlin classes is `Any?` (it is also a superclass of `Any`).

The generic type `T` in your `test` function has no upper bound so it can be a nullable object `Any?`. The error is because you can't a `Comparator<Any>` when you need a `Comparator<Any?>`.

So you can fix your example defining the `T` upper bound as `Any`:

```
fun <T: Any> test() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it indeed helps. Based on your tip, another fix is implementing `Comparator<Any?>` instead of `Comparator<Any>` by AnyComparator.

Comment: `Any` actually is the superclass of all kotlin classes but it is not the supertype of all kotlin types. `KType` has a `isMarkedNullable` property while `KClass` is just the class and classes are not nullable aware. Suggestion: `s/class/type/g`. e.g. `kotlin.Any?` is a supertype of `kotlin.Any` but the classifier for each of those types is `class kotlin.Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the Fabio answer, Any? is not a superclass of all the classes in kotlin but Any is a subtype of Any? to be technically correct. For Example:

```
    val string1: String = "Sarabjit"

// val newString2 : String = null [this does not work as we cannot assign null to a String which cannot hold a null value

    var checkString: String? = newString1

checkString = null //This works like a charm.
```